# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'setEvent'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, and I'm not familiar with object-oriented programming.
Here my main.py:

```
from event import *
#First Try:
Event().setEvent("error","This is an error")
#Second Try:
a=Event()
a.setEvent("error","This is an error")
```

And here my event.py:

```
class Blablaclass:
    .........
    .........
    #Too many codes.

class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        self._eventList = {"error": [], "info": []}
        self._event=""
        self._eventType=""
    def setEvent(self,eventType,event):
        self._eventType=eventType
        self._event=event
        self._eventList[self._eventType].append(self._event)
    def getEvents(self,eventType):
    #This place doesn't have to be right for now. Because I don't even use it.
        self._eventType = eventType
        if self._eventType!="all":
            for iterEvent in self._eventList[eventType]:
                return iterEvent
        else:
            for iterEvent in list(self._eventList["error"]+self._eventList["info"]):
                return iterEvent
```

What is the reason I always get this error?

```
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'setEvent'
```

Comment: Seems to work for me.

Comment: My original codes were much larger than they appeared here. (I'm talking about main.py.) 
I solved the problem by creating a global Event () object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no Python wizard, but I am intrigued by your problem. This seems like something we should be able to crack if no one gives us a direct answer first.

I have combined everything into a single program. Please try to run the following variation of your code and see if it throws the same error. This won't tell us what is going wrong, but it could eliminate some possibilities. If no error is thrown, then we can go back to an imported class but simplified down to the absolute minimum code that generates the error and see what that tells us. But first, lets make sure that it isn't something wonky to your particular python instillation or computer

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        self._eventList = {"error": [], "info": []}
        self._event=""
        self._eventType=""
    def setEvent(self,eventType,event):
        self._eventType=eventType
        self._event=event
        self._eventList[self._eventType].append(self._event)
        print(" setEvent() call executed fine.")

#from event import *
#First Try:
Event().setEvent("error","This is an error")
#Second Try:
a=Event()
a.setEvent("error","This is an error")
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the codes together. It made me see my mistake in my real code.
I solved my problem with global variables. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. As a mater of sound practice, globals shouldn't be used without a dang good reason. The nice thing about classes are that they offer a way around using global variables by encapsulating persistent variables within the class that uses them. The topic which is out of scope to your original question so I will leave it there. Suffice it to say that you should be able to create this class and use its methods without resorting to actual globals. Cheers!